# Dependabot failing to upgrade Ruby dependency

Tags: ruby, bundler, dependabot

I have dependabot integrated into a [github repo](https://github.com/dduugg/yard-sorbet) that I control. I've noticed that dependabot is no longer opening PRs for outdated dependencies, such as `rubocop` and `rubocop-rspec`.

I have an [open ticket](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/5210) in the `dependabot-core` repo that describes the issue in more detail, including a log from an update attempt. However, the developers seem to have abandoned the ticket.

Could someone help me identify and resolve the issue with dependabot upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `rubocop` v1.30.0 [bumped](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-4) the minimum required ruby version to 2.6.

The gemspec in the repo specified the `required_ruby_version` as `>= 2.5.0`, which dependabot seems to consider to be incompatible with the rubocop requirement. (I think this is overly strict, as `rubocop` still supports a a `TargetRubyVersion` of 2.5.)

Nonetheless, [bumping](https://github.com/dduugg/yard-sorbet/commit/b587341dd840c28cabb3d96bbb5e013a0f47efb9) the `required_ruby_version` to `>= 2.6.0` has [unblocked](https://github.com/dduugg/yard-sorbet/pull/99) the dependabot upgrades.